# ESXi 5.5 Unable to connect to a ESXI

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I've lost connection to several ESXi 5.5.

First, I saw they lost connection with vCenter (5.5 SLES Appliance). Then I tried to connect directly to the ESXi using the vSphere Client, and got Error 503 `The server could not interpret the client's request (Error on remote server (503) Server not found.)`
If I try to connect via HTTPS, I get the 503 error, too.

I've restarted management agents several times (GUI and CLI), but this didn't help. After that I ran `~ # services.sh restart` and got this:

```
Starting ntpd
Running DCUI restart
Enabling DCUI login: runlevel =
VobUserLib_Init failed with -1
Running usbarbitrator restart
Errors:
Not all VMFS volumes were updated; the error encountered was 'Timeout'.
Errors:
Not all VMFS volumes were updated; the error encountered was 'Timeout'.
Errors:
Error while scanning interfaces, unable to continue. Error was Not all VMFS volumes were updated; the error encountered was 'Timeout'.
```

Googled that error, and ran `~ # esxcfg-scsidevs -l`, but it seems to be always ok in there. Took a look to `resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts`, and they seem to be ok, too.

It's suspicious, if I run `df -h`, it takes a long long time (and never ends).

Any info will be very appreciated.

Comment: What kind of storage volumes are those?

Comment: VMFS5 Volumes, via Fibre Channel, iSCSI, I see that "Local VMware Disk" is inactive. I tried to run an esxcfg-rescan. But got same error again
     `Error: Not all VMFS volumes were updated; the error encountered was 'Timeout'.`

Comment: Both FC and iSCSI?  What kind of storage is the "Local VMware Disk" volume using?

Comment: "Block SCSI"
Possible SCSI reservation conflict?

Comment: Right, all of those protocols are going to be block SCSI, what I want to know is which interface it's using for that specific disk.  Look at which vmhba that disk is on, then look at what adapter the vmhba ID is.  What makes you think there's a SCSI reservation conflict?

Comment: Found that on vmkernel.log
`2014-07-28T17:40:21.492Z cpu0:38429)lpfc: lpfc_scsi_cmd_iocb_cmpl:2057: 0:(0):3271: FCP cmd x16 failed <1/59> sid x010000, did x013200, oxid xffff SCSI Reservation Conflict -`

Local VMware Disk is at vmhba0

Tried to do  `vmkfstools --lock lunreset /vmfs/devices/disks/mpx.vmhba0\:C0\:T0\:L0`, but vmkernel.log gives me `2014-07-28T17:49:52.248Z cpu6:5115036)Resv: 631: Executed out-of-band lun reset on mpx.vmhba0:C0:T0:L0`

Comment: Again, what type of adapter is `vmhba0`, and what kind of storage is that actual disk?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/U1v35.png

Comment: Device: HP Smart array E200i, Type: "Block SCSI"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16016/discussion-between-mvillar-and-shane-madden).

Comment: Ok, so it's SAS disks local to the server, right? Can you verify that the server's local disks are functioning?

Comment: Yeah, the server have two SAS disks. I don't think local disks were damaged (I have same problem now on 4 ESXi). But I took a look at the server ILO, and seems to be always OK

Comment: Well, it seems like something's not right with that storage - controller or driver problems, maybe.  Have you tried rebooting the host?

Comment: @mvillar Is this an HP ProLiant server? If so, can you provide the model and version?